# Progressive download and streaming of video content using Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, progressive-download

Does Amazon S3 support progressive download? I just want my videos start playing before its fully loaded.

I don't need real streaming yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does is the simple answer.

You'll need to encode your videos in a format that supports playback before the entire file is downloaded and your video player will need to support that too. But those requirements are no different from any other file server.

Comment: @Peter - I dam not familiar with specifics around ogg/theora, but if it works as you want from a normal web host, it will work from S3.